Short story about cost of IP after death
I remember reading a short story about how your mind can be uploaded after death, but you either have to pay for all the IP you remember (e.g. books read, TV shows/movies watched, music listened to) or it gets deleted. Anyone know what it might be?

Sounds like it could be something by Doctorow.  I haven't read this story, but I know I've read about it.

There is a Tom Scott video called "Welcome to Life" with this very plot - is that what you're thinking of?

That's the one! The memory of it being a video must have been deleted.

@parsley72 - Probably you didn't pay for the IP

This is "Welcome To Life" (2013) by Tom Scott - it's a short video rather than a story, but the plot elements match.
At the end,

 The protagonist decides that the real Hades is prefereable to the synthetic one.

